# Website down. Apache seems to be working, sort of… Doesn't even display it works page, just a Index of/

Tags: apache-2.2, vps

[http://imgur.com/Sl3i5JF](https://imgur.com/Sl3i5JF)

I am running an apache web server on a Ramnode vps (ubuntu) and it was running fine till this morning. I go to visit my site now and nothing is up. I directly type the ip address and this is what comes up. It's not even the Apache it works page... I'm so confused. I tried restarting the server and the machine, disabling the firewall and it's still there. Can someone help me.

Comment: That's a directory index. It means your webserver is absolutely fine. Your config has changed. You may look at your .htaccess configuration for handlers and indexes.

Comment: where is that located? in the apache.conf?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have no files in your DocumentRoot directory. Check to see that all the files you expect to be there actually are. Secondly, you may want to double check your apache config to make sure it didn't get overwritten somehow.

Comment: Yes the /var/www/ folder has all the files still

Comment: Your DocumentRoot got changed then, or all requests are now hitting a different virtual host.

Comment: You were right, the DocumentRoot was changed. I have no idea how it happened automatically....  All my other sites are still down though and it seems namecheap is getting DDoS attacked so will have to wait to see if something's wrong with the others.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the webserver is running just fine but you're missing your files / configurtion (possibly both). If it's critical to get your site up and running then recover from your backups and start looking for reason that this happened in your logs.